# How can I know if a branch in a Git repository ever renamed (local)?

Tags: git

I think I made a mistake by renaming an old branch in my company repository (local). Is there a way if I can know if a branch ever renamed in a Git Repository?

Comment: You could check the reflog `git reflog`? I just tried and it clearly shows a branch being renamed `ada143a00 (HEAD -> test2) HEAD@{0}: Branch: renamed refs/heads/test to refs/heads/test2` --- This approach may not work if the change happened a long time ago.

Comment: Damn... put it below~ Thank you so much

Comment: Will do when I get a free moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to find when you renamed a branch. Although this could be buried depending on how long ago it was and how many operations have occured since then.

Here is an example of creating and then renaming the branch `a` to `b`:

```
gch -b a
gb -m b
```

And here is the reflog of those operations (`git reflog`):

```
b0c209a (HEAD -> b, develop) HEAD@{0}: Branch: renamed refs/heads/a to refs/heads/b
b0c209a (HEAD -> b, develop) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from develop to a
```

This can be combined with [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) to search for any branch rename `g reflog | grep 'Branch: renamed'`.